# Is it possible to use a CSS Attribute in a selector in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

For example, imagine I have some HTML that I cannot modify, and CSS that I'm free to modify:

`<ELEMENT>Hello World</ELEMENT>`

and on a different page:

`<ELEMENT>5</ELEMENT>`

Where `ELEMENT` code be any valid HTML element.

Is there any way to say something like:

```
*[style:display=inline] {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
}
```

in order to effectively say "If (and only if) the display is currently `inline`, change it to `inline-block`?

Comment: Only if the style was actually applied inline, _via_ the `style` attribute. In any other situation - nope.

Comment: Well, there are container queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@container It seems to me, that one can build something with the partially supported style queries: `@container foo style(display: inline)`. Although, I think there is no possibility to address `ELEMENT` then, only its children.

Comment: There aren't many inline elements in html so it's probably easier just to write a selector that covers them all

Comment: @Pete - another example of usage would be `*[style:color=#FF0000]` to target anything that is bright red, but sounds like it's not possible in general.

Comment: It's not possible in general because it would create a circularity. The element would be `display:inline` so the rule holds and would set the element to `display:inline-block`. At which point the rule doesn't hold, and so the element would be reverted to `display:inline` and repeat ad infinitum.

Comment: @Alohci - good point, I hadn't thought about that!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it if you are okay with using inline styles on the element.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <span style="display: inline;">Hello</span>
  <span>world</span>
  <style>
    *[style="display: inline;"] {
      color: red;
      display: inline-block !important;
      position: relative;
      top: 1rem;
    }
  </style>
</body>
</html>
```

You need to be careful with selector in CSS as the space between `display:` and `inline;` is required for the comparison to work correctly.

The `display: inline;` needs to be specified inline otherwise it won't be available for CSS. Better option if really needed would be to use `data-display="inline"` and then use `*[data-display="inline"]`. With `data-display` you don't need to add `!important` to style.

> I've added `color: red` and `top: 1rem` to illustrate change between 2 spans.

Comment: I can't modify the HTML, only the CSS. The HTML does not have inline styles unfortunately, and even if they did, I couldn't guarantee that they wouldn't have other inline styles as well.

Comment: Your HTML is thoroughly invalid. You can't put `<style>` where you have it